# How to decrypt OpenID token with Private key in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting OpenID JWT token which is encrypted with Public key, and I have to decrypt it with corresponding private key to use it. How we can do it in C#.

I tried below code but not sure how to pass private key in it. Its reading given token but Payload showing as null.

var token = "eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAtMjU2In0.EC3HaViik4kCCC2eK7FIsWHqsRatYuWvZ3hUzMuUIturPaX8WaflW0nHt2yp_gxLeNYfF89H8Bb4aP4FGjXt5FmuRRfzFS8Gyl1bvQMnErJVZrYWhzfAlT4yV2DvqpbeXvKBxjpLP6HNK4ueK0NFrhdNUGqZCdedGv8-8hCFC1295REpzF9Wo-PSk-JiOXbBlyj_MH3s2HtzF1T_52nI_CIm3urSoD2fmqnhd5rL44yM6n-bjzPUXQ4ob0RdavPhH5jfatIDKa-Xnu4Ya9SVw28BF61ZwK_UQUZz1aaYemXF8qkyi5qTy2hbZ-LiVZjk_Y2HwBgBIy0OQ9IcFbZntQ.odN0_t8gJpDfd9ki.6FQeRttwxVAmQWWbdLfOGPb-AbXriUIOOGQbDXInjUFb3TrH9Ioga2Gp8ZLWQ1TLWsNUC5MHU1NPSfVVLocHr6flQwd8yVCJ9nF_rq6ip_ZRhggMijkDK_hy-IOyjNEXWjtRV-tU3fxZhakXVab7NS8Yl2vkefb1CzkJ14OCzsDHqfgiC5C5khya312A_ti5csDEmhsR_KUC2REfkEbeis6k_dEq3umlRo6Kckh6zS9i2xcLFlREd3GHz69AK8Iv0GSLWmb1w4H4nafN30YTzHyQozv_co7DmY9Mzg4w-Ih3WFHyo4yBZs9JnW2iSVSXJOiDIxt5qhTb8HFDin6y8mjA4oarsnzDEfg7H9D5GGqsNXBAgVif40xcNoMH9K8CIOU4ahoH8HtAmeDIkLEJ9zsnIi1VKzRfaE_0zUj2c3CvkQVkLhbAYSqkpb4KPyAG6NEZ2EXFpPEn4-2Ht9AHd5i6T310GmTkmoxPBJ4xBuA23x2WbVRFd4b9x_cbYZkXLptoQEhA59mBW19GvzD7GRpYxww_rmPYTH0KxaH8E9ApWfnpNJBMJgztXybrbQqEKZQFUQOgJubc67lrPGT-bSNDY48X7p1rETG8NvLSGl1kFjHz-arGAU9U__XG_QnEbL2aNyvuf8lMDV_MS9PCT3grrPNbapW4lZSZPdCr66QpCRP-J60CBpYrcrb1w940uMIUu1vsRMvEMRSylyYbySUwOdGrty0pdm3lYRjEjttJnJYQpH0aER5umFv_HgrbCG3ay29rzBzVS0U7nDGn_3l5K3l5odoM5dp6fkWHNyeCQhrQlvgZJ2oMvDi8_hW9si369srLM9OLjkNgRP5qISPEjn53cBC-iJasZWThBNrNpNDc8BDCKgAeMlUwSw64WXDC64WvKY0290LVhL45DouSET9qkNLNu78ft7deSKgt6Lv0Tup9PNkMbvx1Xmh5yAQ3qjUNNzJ3aXXXWluESnbZqjf2lTJXvQFLYxKl1aG5O8pmK6SLchH_Qi0LyeL8rpqmUdlX6b4XdWFgocgRqCbqAOw9DbJlZce-yf57NA4MbU3AtWBh7doKdYvF9IgTx3ONp-hP7ctbLIdXU-R5nRIYNQNEEbsQl4kcT6CCobq-T4r_r3mCWUGmqteWVBKx-5UOzFSxcKSYSMTrvlyH1xlymKy-OsVT-sK9RqTnvdh87aTyA6aWLa7ijTs8gBMOueEti4IdSISmit6vyc1zKwp1L680wuHLPC00sz0c6fndk5pAld4s_roikVemk6f4BOOydpkAWFjLc72Oep5sxYRKmMcG8yzmfM9f2l6y-_YcHgJ_a30LrwyzvS3DzmmY473gDCBtYhjyZjDWb5CP_rO7J25mjg.hGGg988RdlCkZ1Za1SJzPg";

```
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token);
        var tokenS = jsonToken as JwtSecurityToken;
```

Comment: In general, you need to call the ValidateToken() method on the handler, providing the token, and the various validation parameters, including the appropriate keys such as the IssuerSigningKey and the TokenDecryptionKey. If it validates, you get a validated useful token out.